# using lua scripts with wireshark

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm just getting started in Lua for wireshark
I'm following this tutorial To test the Lua script: [Lua Tutorial](https://delog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/create-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua/)

the script code is in the tutorial.
I have to add the following lines to inite.Lua (at the very end):

```
MYPROTO_SCRIPT_PATH="C:\\myproto\\"  
dofile (MYPROTO_SCRIPT_PATH.."my proto.lua")
```

but how do I see if the script is working as tcp packets coming going to 8002 port are still showing as TCP packet?
do I have to do something before Wireshark starts working with the script or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Lua scripts load on startup of wireshark (that's why you change the init file). If you correctly set the port dissection in your lua file (and the file is located in the correct location...namely where you have your path pointing "C:\myproto\") then you should see it working.  Trying opening a pcap file and look at a packet to see if it gives you any lua warnings/errors.